# ROpenNLP: Part of Speech (POS) Annotation hang on large file

Tags: r, nlp, opennlp, rscript, part-of-speech

The Following script work really fine and fast to make tag annotation with a file below +-4000 lines.
Above more than this approximate 4000 lines the script hangs. And never process the data.
Input file is plain text and is given in argument to the R script using bash script

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript
require("NLP")
require("openNLP")
library(rJava)

args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)
s <- readLines(args)
s <- as.String(s)
sent_token_annotator <- Maxent_Sent_Token_Annotator()
#sent_token_annotator
word_token_annotator <- Maxent_Word_Token_Annotator()
#word_token_annotator
a2 <- annotate(s,
           list(sent_token_annotator,
                word_token_annotator))
#s[a2]
pos_tag_annotator <- Maxent_POS_Tag_Annotator()
pos_tag_annotator
a3 <- annotate(s, pos_tag_annotator, a2)
a3w <- subset(a3, type == "word")
tags <- sapply(a3w$features, "[[", "POS")
sprintf("%s/%s", s[a3w], tags)
```

Comment: Try adding an explicit `gc` in there.  I know you aren't supposed to but I found using `gc` every so often helps.  I think it may be a Java issue.  Currently, your code isn't reproducible as I don't think you give data.  Using `rep(x, 5000)` could give you a reproducible data set with out using your entire data set.

Comment: running the current script to reproduce would require to have the proper R packages installed. 
    require("NLP")
    require("openNLP")
    library(rJava)


And then running the script with has argument the path of the file  (which is currently any plain text (English text) with more than +-4000 lines)

ex:
`./mysrscript.R "/var/tmp/myfile.txt"`

Comment: Both option you are suggesting seem interesting. But I have no Idea how I should implement this with my current script. Would appreciate if you could give me some example

Comment: I can't as I'm not 100% sure what your code does as it does not run for me.  I indeed have these packages installed but not your data.  The idea with a reproducible example is that someone can grab your code and run it and get the same result you're getting (or at least on a smaller scale).  See this for help: http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-make-a-minimal-reproducible-example-to-get-.html  Once we have data to run with your code we can provide suggestions tailored to the example.

Comment: Thanks. Here is a sample: https://www.dropbox.com/s/y89h6fh4p7auipy/EcHistRome.txt

Comment: Has you will notice. The script hangs almost at the begining and will stay at this state for ever
`./mysrscript.R EcHistRome.txt`
will output the following and hang:
`Loading required package: NLP
Loading required package: openNLP
Loading required package: methods
An annotator inheriting from classes
  Simple_POS_Tag_Annotator Annotator
with description
  Computes POS tag annotations using the Apache OpenNLP Maxent Part of
  Speech tagger employing the default model for language 'en'`